# Increasing card sequence game; expected number of cards in hand

Tags: probability, expected-value

> There are N cards. The i-th card has integer i written on it.
>
> You first shuffle N cards randomly and put them in a pile. Take the card at the top of the pile to your hand. Then repeat the following process until the pile becomes empty:
>
> Check the card on the top of the pile.
> If the number on the card is larger than the number on the last card you took, take the card.
> Otherwise, discard the card.
> The score of the game is the number of cards in your hand at the end. With the given number of cards N, what is the expected score of the game?

This is a coding problem from Google Kick Start. The answer is the $N$th harmonic number $H_N$. They do give a nice probabilistic solution in the analysis section. But the solution reminded me of the coupon collector's problem, where the answer is $n\; H_n$. So I want to know if a similar strategy would work here.

My initial thought:

1. Create an indicator variable $I_j$ which is $1$ if we keep the $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ card.
2. Then, since we repeat the experiement $N$ times, linearity gives $E = \sum_{j=1}^N Pr[I_j]$.
3. In a randomly shuffled set of cards, all cards would be equally likely. So, the probability for the drawn card to be kept after drawing the first card would be $1/2$ for $N - 1$ cards, hence giving the answer $ \frac{N - 1}{2} + 1 = \frac{N + 1}{2}$.

This answer is not correct and I think my mistake is assuming that the probability remains constant as $j$ changes. Since each time we keep a card, the number of cards that would be larger than the last card I put in my hand keeps shrinking, the probability won't be a constant.

An alternate method, inspired by the way to solve the coupon collector problem was, same steps as (1) and (2) but find $Pr[I_j]$ in the following way:

1. When I pick the $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ card, if I decide to keep that card, that means that card is the largest card among the $j$ cards I have picked / considered.
2. Since we are considering $j$ cards and the deck is randomly shuffled, the probability of my specific card being the largest among the $j$ cards is $1 / j$, as any of the $j$ cards could have been the largest.
3. This means $E = \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j} = H_n$.

While this matches the answer, I'm not sure if I got the correct answer in an incorrect manner. Is my line of reasoning for the solution correct?

Comment: Your second set of 1, 2, 3 arguments looks correct and is close to what I would have said.